# EasyAdmin 3.1 Error trying to make a dashboard

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I am using Symfony 5.0 and EasyAdmin 3.1.

No idea why EasyAdmin tries to call an undefined function... Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Just for future reference, [avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.  Images are difficult to read and even more difficult to copy/paste from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the *composer.json* file fixed it.

`"symfony/string": "5.0.*"` had to be changed to   `"symfony/string": "5.1.*"`

then calling

```
composer update "symfony/*"
```

in the Terminal to update.